# Selecting an <iframe> inside of an <a> tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a script to display a lightbox when a thumbnail is clicked, and it worked perfectly for pictures. I realized I needed videos, not pictures, though, and my changes to the script don't seem to be working. How do I select the iframe inside the clicked anchor tag to display the video? This is the HTML and JQuery:

HTML

```
<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <img class="big_img" src="#">
</div>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="body">

        <li class="responsive">
            <div class=image>
                <a href="#" class="lightbox"><img class="gallery thumbnail" src="../pics/placeholder.png"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UAQ9-sl13zg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></a>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </li>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".thumbnail").click(function() {
            var video = $("iframe",this).attr("src");
            $('.big_img').attr("src",video);
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.close').click(function(){
            close_box();
        });

        $('.backdrop').click(function(){
            close_box();
        })
    });

    function close_box()
    {
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I see an issue with "$('.big_img').attr("src", video);". You are setting an image source to a link to a video. That won't work

Comment: Doesn't make sense putting an iframe inside an `<a>`.

Comment: You should just place an iframe with an empty source right below your image tag, and conditionally show/hide them based on whether an image or video is clicked. I think that would be the easiest solution at this point.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. I'll try that out.

Comment: I'm still trying to solve the other question of selecting that iframe, now in the same parent div as the anchor tag.

Comment: @BJohnson Yeah, you cannot nest an iframe inside of an <a> tag. It is not valid HTML. You'll have to move the iframe outside of the <a> tag as a sibling, and change your selector to the following: var video = $(this).closest(".image").find("iframe").attr("src");

Comment: Sweet, I changed it. I also changed .big_img to an <iframe> with a class of .big_vid, but nothing happens still. :/